# What the "Global" adjective means when talking about EDIFACT messages?

Tags: edifact

My question could also be summarized as... What the "Global" means in (for example) "Global INVOIC" instead of just "INVOIC".

My guess is that the EDIFACT standard added some features, and from that time the version of EDIFACT messages allowed them to be used for "global" comunication. It seems to me that the year was 2000 (D00.A). But I did not find any explicit reference.

Is it true or what is the reason?

**Update:**

I have found the following note a bit later in the `EN VDA 4938 Part 2 Global INVOIC V2.2 July 2016.pdf` that can be downloaded as part of the zip file from
https://www.vda.de/en/services/Publications/global-invoic-implementation-guideline.html

> This part 2 of the recommendation contains the message implementation
>   **guideline for the UN/EDIFACT message INVOIC** and is a **subset of the
>   Global INVOIC**, which has been developed jointly by **AIAG, JAMA/JAPIA
>   and Odette for use in the automotive industry**. Detailed information
>   regarding the process requirements are described in part one of this
>   recommendation.

(Emphasized by myself.) Anyway, the document uses the word *global* only on few places, and it does not clarify it. However it uses *Global INVOIC* (with capital G) that suggests that it is a formal term.

Can anyone (possibly from the automotive industry) clarify the difference to the UN/EDIFACT?

Comment: I've been dealing with B2B EDI messages for a couple of years now and haven't heard that term yet. I wouldn't expect it to be anything important, maybe more of a marketing declaration than anything of technical relevance.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek: Thanks. I have added the update to the question.